# Character to numeric summary failure

Tags: r, character, numeric

I have a data frame that contains 3 sets of numbers that I am trying to convert to numeric to do analysis on it.

For example:

```
data <- c("453", "021", "203", "675", "919", "138", "645", "774", "309", 
"351", "129", "428", "435", "704", "725", "530", "952", "008", 
"875", "016", "816", "047", "024", "186", "560", "165", "395", 
"969", "459", "213", "932", "987", "212", "441", "242", "930", 
"319", "327", "064", "194", "453", "129", "680", "998", "208", 
"377", "880", "498", "789", "460", "578", "167", "843", "421", 
"306", "429", "540", "744", "575", "423", "546")
```

The problem is that some of the numbers start with 0 so I can't turn them into numeric because if I do I will lose the "0".

Is there a way to work around this so I can use `summary(data)` to get an accurate summary of the data?

Comment: "so I can't turn them into numeric because if I do I will loose the "0"." If that is a concern these values are not numeric and should not be converted to numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to use the correct method for `summary`

```
summary.factor(data)
```

By default, it requires a `factor` or `numeric` class to return the frequency count.  If it is `character`, it returns the `length`, `class` and `mode`.  So, either convert it to `factor` to select the appropriate method by `summary` or explicitly call `summary.factor`

---

A better option would be `table` which works on all of the above classes

```
table(data)
```